# Can I put a SATA2 HDD into a laptop supporting SATA1?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, sata

I have a laptop that supports SATA1 (1.5 GB/sec)

The HDD for it has bad sectors, and I want to buy another one.
It seems that where I live, SATA1 notebook HDDs aren't really available (only if you wait for a few weeks for them to be delivered), and they cost more than SATA2 HDDs.

So I was wondering if I buy a SATA2 (3GB/sec) HDD, will it work without problems on my laptop?

The laptop is an HP Pavilion DV6000

EDIT: Are there any downsides to putting a SATA2 HDD into a SATA1 laptop? Is there any reason I wouldn't want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  it is backward compatible. (I actually tried/used it in a friend's PC so no, not a copypasta answer.)

The link to prrove this:

> The designers of SATA aimed for
>   backward and forward compatibility
>   with future revisions of the SATA
>   standard

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Backward_and_forward_compatibility).

Comment: OK. Is there any reason I might not want do do what I want to do? Are there any downsides to putting a SATA2 HDD into a SATA1 laptop?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Wait until someone else also writes down his experience.

Comment: @user22559: As a sidenote. CHECK it before you buy. It might not work due to the laptop AND it might have a hardware restriction in the means of size. Just ask for a HDD of a friend, check the BIOS and there you go. If everything seems ok, turn it off. You don't even have to boot that HDD.